# Error generating Birt report

Tags: internet-explorer-6, tomcat6, birt

When I try to open birt report in IE 6 (only browser I have, since it is old production server), i got message:

```
Line: 85
Char: 1
Error: Object expected
Code: 0
```

Report opens blank and Parameters screen do not show.

I am using this version of birt:
- Viewer Version : 2.5.1
- Engine Version: 2.5.1
- JRE version: 1.6.0_18

And this is .rptdesign data that I am using:

```
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.o...irt/2005/design" version="3.2.6" id="1">
<property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 2.5.2.v20100208 Build &lt;2.5.2.v20100210-0630></property>
```

This data was taken from previous reports that work.

My orignal .rptdesign data is:

```
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.o...irt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
<property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 3.7.2.v20120213 Build &lt;3.7.2.v20120214-1408></property>
```

Note that I am running Birt on Tomcat 6.0 .

I don't know if you need any more information, but if you do, please let me know.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a report created in  Version 3.7.2.v20120213  using an older version of BIRT.  You can only run a report in a newer version of BIRT then it was created.

Comment: But, I was able earlier to run reports with newer versions of Designer than runtime versions.
I just edit XML tags in .rptdesigner file like shown in my inquiry and thats that. 
But in this case this workaround does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2.5 reports on BIRT 3.7.  But you cannot run 3.7 reports on BIRT 2.5.  Newer versions have newer features, BIRT looks to see what version designer version was used to create the report before running it.  If you try to run a report created in version 3.7 on BIRT 2.5, it just won't run it.  If it is simple report, you can get around this by copy and paste; Copy the design version from the xml of the 2.5 into the 3.7.  BIRT will think it was created in 2.5 and run it.

Of course if the report uses anything new from the 3.7 version that is not supported by the 2.5 software, it won't work.  But if it is a simple table, it should be fine.

Comment: My report contains 2 tables with table groups, aggregation (sum) and input parameters (some of them are list boxes with dynamic list values).
Do you maybe know, are some of them unsupported for the BIRT 2.5.?

Comment: @AcoVujic I am sorry I don't know that.